# Was ist der Hauptunterschied zwischen merkwürdig, seltsam und komisch?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, usage, meaning-in-context

Was ist der Hauptunterschied zwischen ***merkwürdig***, ***seltsam*** und ***komisch***?

Alle bedeuten "weird/strange" auf Englisch, oder?

Comment: Es gibt keinen. Es sind drei verschiedene Wörter, die alle in ihrer Bedeutung ähnlich sind. Der Duden beispielsweise verweist in seiner Bedeutungsübersicht jeweils auf die anderen. Aber das ist auch kein Unterschied zum Englischen. Alleine "seltsam" ist strange, weird, odd, queerly, ...

Comment: Eine etwas in den Hintergrund getretene (veraltete?) Bedeutung von *merkwürdig* ist *des Merkens würdig*, also erinnernswert. Im Meyer aus dem 19. Jahrhundert ist das noch eher die gebräuchliche: "das 1851 aufgeführte Gebäude der Töchterschule, mit architektonisch merkwürdigem Kreuzgang" oder "Übersicht der merkwürdigsten Porträtstatuen".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Bedeutung ist praktisch identisch. Jedoch gibt es einen Unterschied in Bezug auf die Sprachebene.

In förmlicher Sprache würde man "komisch" kaum verwenden, "seltsam" schon eher, und "merkwürdig" noch wahrscheinlicher. Denke an einen Brief an deinen Vorgesetzten oder an eine Behörde.

Ganz auf der sicheren Seite zur Wahrung eines höflichen, überlegten Tons wäre "befremdlich" oder "verwunderlich". Ganz der informellen Sprache zueigen wäre "schräg".

Listen wir sie also in absteigender Reihenfolge der Verwendbarkeit in förmlichen Kontexten auf:

> verwunderlich
>
> befremdlich
>
> merkwürdig
>
> seltsam
>
> komisch
>
> schräg

Uh... I am not quite sure about the position of "befremdlich" and "verwunderlich". Perhaps they are completely interchangeable... but with the lengthy "verwunderlich" at top they form a nice inverted pyramid. :-)

Comment: Dankeschön. Sehr hilfreich.

Comment: One more difference: In contrast to the other words in this list, "komisch" has the additional (and in fact, original) meaning "comical", "funny".

Comment: Nach meinem Empfinden: befremdlich ist ablehnender als verwunderlich, merkwürdig ist schwächer als seltsam

Comment: ... man könnte natürlich ein dreidimensionales Koordinatenfeld aufstellen mit den Dimensionen Grad der Förmlichkeit, Grad der Ablehnung und Ausdrucksstärke...

Comment: Für mich ist "merkwürdig" weniger wertend als "seltsam". "Merkwürdig" ist eher so wie "bemerkenswert".